# async/await WhenAll on two methods with the same return type

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to upload files asynchronously to an S3 bucket. I'm able to do that successfully with the following code.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to process two different methods that have the same return type simultaneously.

`UploadImages` and `UploadAttachments` both return an `IEnumerable` of `EntityUploadResult`. How do I execute them in Parallel and return the results after they have both completed?

```
public async Task<List<EntityUploadResult>> BulkUploadFiles(IEnumerable<BulkUploadFile> files)
{
    var results = new List<EntityUploadResult>();

    var images = UploadImages(files.Where(x => x.FileType == BulkFileType.Image).AsEnumerable());
    var attachments = UploadAttachments(files.Where(x => x.FileType == BulkFileType.Attachment).AsEnumerable());

    results.AddRange(await images);
    results.AddRange(await attachments);

    return results;
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<EntityUploadResult>> UploadImages(IEnumerable<BulkUploadFile> files)
{
    return await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(i => UploadImage(i)));
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<EntityUploadResult>> UploadAttachments(IEnumerable<BulkUploadFile> files)
{
    return await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(i => UploadAttachment(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, that's what you're already doing by starting both operations and only then awaiting them.

But, if you want to do that with `Task.WhenAll` and await only once you can use the return value which is a collection of the all the operations' return values and combine them with `SelectMany`

```
public async Task<List<EntityUploadResult>> BulkUploadFiles(IEnumerable<BulkUploadFile> files)
{
    var images = UploadImages(files.Where(x => x.FileType == BulkFileType.Image).AsEnumerable());
    var attachments = UploadAttachments(files.Where(x => x.FileType == BulkFileType.Attachment).AsEnumerable());

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(images, attachments);
    return results.SelectMany(_ => _).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`await` on a `WhenAll` with them both, then examine the `Result` later or if (as in this case) via the returned result of the `WhenAll`:

If the two types are different you can do this (also an option if the types are the same);

```
await Task.WhenAll(images, attachments);
var imgResult = images.Result;
var attResult = attachments.Result;
```

When they are of the same type you can also do:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<EntityUploadResult>> = await Task.WhenAll(images, attachments);
```

As such your lines:

```
results.AddRange(await images);
results.AddRange(await attachments);
```

Could be replaced with:

```
results.AddRange((await Task.WhenAll(images, attachments)).SelectMany(u => u));
```

Comment: One minor note: `Result` will wrap any exceptions in an `AggregateException`, whereas `await` more naturally throws the original exception type. For this reason, I prefer `await` over `Result` even for completed tasks.

Comment: @StephenCleary true, but since the `await Task.WhenAll(…)` does that in itself, it'll either throw (unwrapped) at that point, or else if we get past it `Result` will return the already-obtained result without throwing.